# Are there any tools to view a process' thread control blocks?

Tags: linux-kernel, process, process-management, thread

Process Control Blocks expose the /proc file system which allows PCBs to be read by users.  Is there a similar file system for Thread Control Blocks?  If not, is there a tool to read their contents (bonus points if it supports high-frequency sampling)?

Comment: Does `/proc/.../task` give the info you’re after?

Comment: I'm interested in the program counter, register contents, and thread state.  Where would I find that in the proc/{pid}/task/{tid} directory?

Answer (score 4):

The Kernel has a Thread Control Block (TCB). To view the information you're after, I would use -

`# cat /proc/PID/task/PID/status`

So, to view thread information for a process that has the PID 12345 -

`# cat /proc/12345/task/12345/status`

There's also libproc, [available in procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/). Sorry, I couldn't provide good documentation on that.

Comment: Which entries in the `cat .../status` output correspond to program counter, register contents, and thread state?

Comment: Please consult the docs at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: Another excellent piece of insights at [this blog](https://tanelpoder.com/2013/02/21/peeking-into-linux-kernel-land-using-proc-filesystem-for-quickndirty-troubleshooting/)